API functions timed out after deployment to vercel
api/index.js
import authRoutes from "../routes/authRoute.js"
import userRoutes from "../routes/userRoute.js"
import productRoutes from "../routes/productRoute.js"
import orderRoutes from "../routes/orderRoute.js"

const corsOptions = {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173/"],
    methods: ["POST", "GET", "PUT"],
    credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Node API server!");
});

app.use("api/v1/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("api/v1/user", userRoutes)
app.use("api/v1/product", productRoutes)
app.use("api/v1/order", orderRoutes)

vercel.json
{ "version": 2, "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }] }

Till now after I fixed the project structure by following the docs from vercel website, at least the / route is running but all the other routes are still could not found even I followed the correct structure.
I followed the deployment guide step by step in Vercel documentation but still had error occurred at last

Are you sure that you have imported each of these authRoutes,userRoutes,productRoutes,orderRoutes in routes/index.js file ?
And if you are getting any other error then also mention that.

Yes I did import all of them

This may be helpful for you. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276674/vercel-serverless-function-has-timed-out-error

Is it related to MongoDB network problem as I put my URL in environmental variables?

the shared link is the solution for this This Serverless Function has timed out error.Here you can find the reasons for which this particular error gets triggered.

But now I fixed the code and the other routes could not be read

Instead is it possible to upgrade the plan to extend the limit of execute time?

I am not sure about that. But I am sure that you can do it by configuring vercel.json  & route.js. for more detailed info check the link https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/duration

If I am using MongoDB database what will be the suitable execution time? Instead I am also wondering if render or netlify will be more suitable than vercel if backend is using Node JS?
